# Genesis Framework - How to switch main hook and sidebar hook order

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks, hook, genesis

I recently started using Genesis Framework and am still getting accustomed to the hooks used to create the layout.

The page I am designing uses the left sidebar as main navigation. It works great until it collapses on smaller screens; the sidebar goes to the bottom, below the main content.

I tried searching for a solution since it seems it may be something common, but no success.

The process that I think would solve it is to use remove_action to remove sidebar and main content to then bring them back with add_action in a different order. For this I need to know the exact name of the hooks and the order number (if specified).

Please let me know what you think would solve this and, if I am in the right track, how would you change the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you need, here's the answer to your question.

This is how you remove the page content.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
```

This is how you remove the sidebar in a page.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'genesis_do_sidebar' );
```

And this is the hooks before content and sidebar.

```
genesis_before_content
```

In your case let's use this codes in functions.php

```
remove_action( 'genesis_sidebar', 'genesis_do_sidebar' );
add_action( 'genesis_before_content', function(){
    echo '<aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" role="complementary" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">';
    echo genesis_do_sidebar();
    echo '</aside>';
}, 2 );
```

Hope this can help you in the future.

Comment: That's perfect! I have yet to try it, but it is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The solution that I found is a fix with CSS, using [Flexbox](http://flexboxin5.com/).

It is pretty simple, but I would have liked to fix the problem at the source, not find something to cover it up.

It is done with media queries along with the screen size when it collapses.
The CSS fix is to:

1. Apply {display: flex; flex-direction: column;} to the containing element, and
2. apply {order: 2;} to the element that appears first, but I wanted second.

Let me know what you think and/or what would have done differently.